# phpseclib - issues with php versions

Tags: php, phpseclib

Running on PHP 5.2.13 this works fine :

each line of output is shown..

```
include('includes/Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('127.0.0.1');

if (!$ssh->login('root', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

function packet_handler($str)
{
    echo $str;
}

$ssh->exec('ping 127.0.0.1', 'packet_handler');
```

Running the same code on PHP 5.3.17 returns nothing.

I'd have to use something like

```
echo $ssh->exec('timeout 5 ping 127.0.0.1');
```

And wait for it to time out.

Any idea why this isn't working on the new version ?

Thanks

Comment: PHP 5.2 and 5.3 have a lot of differences. try add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` into begin of your script and it will show you errors.

Comment: Thanks - I've added that and re run the script it just keeps running - no errors etc are shown on screen or in the error_log !

Comment: What version Net_SSH2 are you using?

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem isn't due to your sapi. Like maybe you're trying to run the script via Apache and you're not flush()ing. Or maybe you are flush()ing and it just doesn't work because of yoru sapi or something (eg. mod_php vs php / cgi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use new NET_SSH2 version. I used composer and your code work well for me (I have PHP 5.6 on my local PC). My steps was:

1) I created new empty folder

2) Run composer:

> composer require "phpseclib/phpseclib"

this will create `vendor` folder with NET_SSH2 version = 0.3.9

3) Then I changed your source code (for composer autoload):

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('127.0.0.1');

if (!$ssh->login('root', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

function packet_handler($str) {
    echo $str;
}

$ssh->exec('ping 127.0.0.1', 'packet_handler');
```

And all work well. I think you have the problem because you are using old library version. You can try use composer or just download new library version from GitHub.

I hope it will help.

Comment: Upgrading the version of phpseclib to a newer release resolved this for me.